# how to join files in unix without sorting

Tags: sorting, unix, csv, join

I am trying to join 2 csv files based on a key in unix.

My files are really huge 5GB each and sorting them is taking too long.

I want to repeat this procedure for 50 such joins.

Can someone tell me how to join without sorting and quickly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the example  with two files having data delimited by pipe

Data from employee.csv with key employee_id, Name and department_id delimited by pipe.

Employee.csv

```
4|John | 10
1|Monica|4
12|Louis|5
20|Peter|2
21|David|3
13|Barbara|6
```

Department file with deparment_id and its name delimited by pipe.
Dept.csv

```
1|HR
2| Manufacturing
3| Engineering
4 |Marketing
5| Sales
6| Information technology
7| Security
```

command:

```
join -t “|” -1 3 -2 1 Employee_sort.csv Dept.csv
```

-t “| ” indicated files are delimited by pipe

-1 3 for third column of file 1 i.e deparment_id from Employee_sort.csv file

-2 1 for first column of file 2 i.e. deparment_id from Dept.csv file

By using above command, we get following output.

```
2|20|Peter| Manufacturing
3|21|David| Engineering
4|1|Monica| Marketing
5|12|Louis| Sales
6|13|Barbara| Information technology
```

If you want to get everything from file 2  and corresponding entries in file 1

You can also use -a and -v options

try following commands

```
join -t “|” -1 3 -2 1 -v2 Employee_sort.csv Dept.csv
join -t “|” -1 3 -2 1 -a2 Employee_sort.csv Dept.csv
```

Comment: I don't see how it answers the question. Your files are already sorted. The asker had theirs unsorted.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no way around the sorting. But please take a look at some utility scripts I have written here: (https://github.com/stefan-schroedl/tabulator). You can use them if you keep the header of the column names as the first line in each file. There is a script 'tbljoin' that will take care of the sorting and column counting for you. For example, say you have

*Employee.csv:*

```
employee_id|employee_name|department_id
4|John|10
1|Monica|4
12|Louis|5
20|Peter|2
21|David|3
13|Barbara|6
```

Dept.csv:

```
department_id|department_name
1|HR
2|Manufacturing
3|Engineering
4|Marketing
5|Sales
6|Information technology
7|Security
```

Then the command `tbljoin Employee.csv Dept.csv` produces

```
employee_id|employee_name|department_id|department_name
20|Peter|2|Manufacturing
21|David|3|Engineering
1|Monica|4|Marketing
12|Louis|5|Sales
13|Barbara|6|Information technology.
```

tabulator contains many other useful features, e.g., for simple rearranging of columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could avoid using join (and thus sorting your file), but this is not a quick solution :

1. In both files, replace all pipes and all double-spaces with spaces :

`sed -i 's/|/ /g;s/  / /g' Employee.csv Dept.csv`

2. run these code lines as a bash script :

`cat Employee.csv | while read a b c
    do
            cat Dept.csv | while read d e
            do
                    if [ "$c" -eq "$d" ] ; then
                            echo -e "$a\t$b\t$c\t$e"
                    fi
            done
    done`

3. Note that looping takes a long time